# Can Darlene from Mr. Robot read Chinese?

Tags: character, mr-robot

In the latest episode of Mr Robot ("eps2.6_succ3ss0r.p12"), in the very last scene we see Cisco's computer screen, which shows a messaging app and an entirely Chinese language set (ok, I'm not *sure* it's Chinese, but I think that's the implication since he's likely talking to the dark army). The Chinese is translated into captions, and Darlene "acts as if she could read it" (if you haven't seen that yet...).

Cisco is a member of the dark army, so I'm ok with him reading Chinese. But can Darlene read Chinese? She's not dark army, and knowledge of the Chinese language (for an American) is just not the same as knowing something like French or Spanish. I mean, she seems to know what the Chinese translation is for "femtocell".

Do we have any evidence besides this scene that Darlene can read Chinese?

Edit/Update: Well, in last night's episode we didn't really get confirmation one way or the other! When they were tapping the phone, she was listening to the conversation but it was also being translated live on the screen. Was that just for our benefit, or maybe her spoken Chinese is not as good as her written?

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct evidence that Darlene can read Chinese. However, the image of her asleep, which she sees on the screen, sent in a chat with someone could be the reason why she hit him with the bat.

The subtitles was for the audience to understand (and probably confuse).

Comment: right, so you're saying just "me sleeping + chinese" is enough for her to hit Sisco with a bat? I might agree with that.

Comment: I would modify that "Image of me sleeping sent on a chat with dark army, when he was the one who invited me to crash at his place, so this all seems like he is spying on me coz he has been with me since really long since days now... I should hit him with a bat" is enough for her to hit Cisco with a bat

Answer (score 0):

Since Darlene can't understand spoken Mandarin, she probably can't read Chinese either.

(Some ethnic Chinese might be able to read Chinese without understanding Mandarin, but this is true of nearly zero non-ethnic Chinese in 2015 who'd certainly have learnt to read Chinese alongside learning the Mandarin language.)

(Also, if Darlene could read Chinese, in S02E09, she'd probably also transcribe the Mandarin speech she's intercepting to Chinese, in case the translations weren't correct. Translation is not perfect in 2023 and was even less perfect back in 2015. Instead she reads only the translated English text.)

> ok, I'm not sure it's Chinese

Yes it's Chinese.

> Darlene "acts as if she could read it"

Even in 2015, anyone could easily translate Chinese text to English. (For example, copy text, paste text into Google translate, done. No need to be a hacker.)

Comment: @Joachim: Since Darlene can't understand spoken Mandarin, she probably can't read Chinese either.